# Sorting libraries available with Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on some sorting of data on the frontend and using VueJS in the application.

Instead of writing the logic for sorting, I want to know is there any library I can use for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of libraries you can use for sorting.

But, are you just looking for Vue.js specific libraries for sorting?
If yes, then which version of Vue.js is your application running?

If you're on Vue.js 1 then you can simply use the orderBy filter.

You need to import and use the lodash instead, if you are on Vue.js 2.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-orderBy-Filter

Another one you can use is Vuetify, a material component framework for Vue.js 2.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables

Apart from Vue.js, you can use the Bootstrap data table and many other options are out there.

Also, next time include some code in your question highlighting the issue you're stuck on instead of asking some theoretical question whose answer you can get on Google.